# How to access softwares installed by local user in domain user account

Tags: dns, active-directory, user-accounts, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed a lot of application and utility software on my laptop using my local windows 8.1 account. recently i have joined a company where i got a domain account, when i joined the company domain and logged in using domain account i couldn't find most of my application that is available when log in using local account. how can i make those software applications available in my domain account as well rather than to re-install all of them.

Another question is that I have administrative rights and even then when try to install any software on any client pc i need to provide the administrative user password. how can I make it so it do not ask me administrative user password when i install any software on any client.

I have the administrative rights with domain user account and i can modify my domain user account easily.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify, I am **assuming** you are using the start menu & desktop (and NOT the metro tiles).

First task, make programs available to both local and domain logins.  (Substitute your actual login names for local-user and domain-user.)

While logged in as domain-user, use Windows Explorer to browse to C:\Users\local-user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
You will see there the shortcuts (and folders for shortcuts) for the programs you can't find logged in as domain-user.  You *should* be able to double-click these shortcuts to launch the programs, no harm in trying it to verify.

You can then move these shortcuts (and shortcut folders) to be available to "all users" on the laptop by moving them to the folder: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs.

Second task, eliminate the annoying the administrator prompts.

Open Control Panel > Users > Change User Account Control settings (middle of window) --- move the slider at left all the way to the bottom "Never notify".
You will be prompted for administrator credentials to confirm you want to do this.